# Is it possible to load an image as a System.Drawing.Bitmap in pages?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I am dealing with loading System.Drawing.Bitmap from image files that are quite large. This often leads to an OutOfMemoryException being thrown.

I've seen schemes that involve scaling the image down at runtime, but this doesn't solve the initial problem. To scale them down, I'd have to load the original image into memory first.

I'd like to load portions of the image instead of the whole file. Is this possible out of the box?

Comment: do you dispose the old objects?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.